# PHP unable to get ENV variable set by Vagrant

Tags: php, vagrant

I have seen a few posts and solutions here, but so far none of them seem to work for me. I'm using Vagrant 1.8.1 on Windows 7 64-bit with the env plugin installed and enabled `config.env.enable` in Vagrantfile. [UPDATE] I'm perhaps doing something wrong or missing something?

I am trying to set a `string=123abc` kind of environment variable.
I started with the inline provisioning in the Vagrantfile:

```
config.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
  echo "export MY_SVR_HOST=192.168.33.10" > /home/vagrant/.profile
SHELL
```

I tried `source /home/vagrant/.profile` underneath (after the echo) but it did not work..

I then tried adding the source line to a provisioning file (bootstrap.sh)

Also (in the bootstrap file) tried `vagrant ssh && source /home/vagrant/.profile && exit` which did not work either.  Note, there is a line in the bootstrap file that restarts apache.

I tried to set a var = value in the `php.ini` file

```
; arbitrary, set host IP for Vagrant
vm_host_ip=192.168.33.10
```

That also did not work. I tried (in httpd.conf) to add
`SetEnv VMHOSTIP "192.168.33.10"`

Then (in a shared php file) I basically wanted the shell to print_r on both $_SERVER and $_ENV to see if any of the above attempts were able to properly set the environment var so that PHP could access its value.

The only thing that came close to working, was the initial attempt of using the inline provision to echo the export command.  However, it only set the environment variable if I did the following:

```
vagrant up --provision
vagrant ssh
source /home/vagrant/.profile
```

[EDIT]
Could be I'm doing something wrong.  Based on the above, is there anything I'm missing?. For now I'll just source the file manually once I've ssh'd into the host serve?

Thanks in advance.

**[EDIT]** I'm adding the inline provision block in the event it may help others in future.

```
# privileged false acts like a sudo, so we can do commands as root.
config.vm.provision "shell", privileged: false, inline: <<-SHELL
  echo "export MY_SVR_HOST=192.168.33.10" > /home/vagrant/.profile

# Add 2 lines (comment and command) to .bashrc if they are not already there.
if grep -Fxq "# source our profile" /home/vagrant/.bashrc
then
  # do nothing since we found the target text.
  echo "we found the source line we need in .bashrc \n"
else
  # Add the lines (comment and command) to .bashrc 
  echo "# source our profile" | tee -a /home/vagrant/.bashrc
  echo "source /home/vagrant/.profile" | tee -a /home/vagrant/.bashrc
fi
SHELL
```

This approach:

- Is based on some helpful tips provided in accepted answer and other research.
- Sets variable when doing `vagrant reload --provision` or complete cycle of `vagrant destroy, vagrant up`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do

```
  config.vm.provision "shell", privileged: false, inline: <<-SHELL
    echo "export MY_SVR_HOST=192.168.33.10" > /home/vagrant/.profile
  SHELL
```

as doing so the `.profile` file would be owned by vagrant user - in your case the file is owned by root so can end up with issue.

If you still get issue, you can do `source` within the provision block so mimic exactly what you're doing manually

```
  config.vm.provision "shell", privileged: false, inline: <<-SHELL
    echo "export MY_SVR_HOST=192.168.33.10" > /home/vagrant/.profile
    source /home/vagrant/.profile
  SHELL
```

Comment: Hi, tried it and it seemed to work ok, however it did not place the var into the environment.  After all was done, I SSH'd in to the host and did command `echo $MY_SVR_HOST` and was expecting the value, but it was empty (nothing printed to shell).  I added the 2 commands from your "if you still get issue" block at end of your answer.

Comment: its weird, it should just work, even no need of the env plugin for this. whats you bash ? I tried with default `ubuntu/wily64` box and then on login I have `vagrant@ubuntu:~$ echo $MY_SVR_HOST
192.168.33.10`

Comment: I have a feeling that you're right. It should work, as that pattern makes the most sense to do. The other ideas (of changing php.ini or httpd.conf) were terrible in hindsight, so I took them out.  I'm now trying to get Vagrant to execute a PHP script that puts a variable/value into `$_ENV` instead of the OS symbol table, and that approach isn't working so well either. I think it's going to just have to be, ssh in and then manually invoke "source"... thanks for your help anyway. Much appreciated.

Comment: can you try to copy the variable into `.bashrc` file for example to see if it'd work.

Comment: Frédéric Henri, thanks for your help. I tried copying the variable to .bashrc but it did not set the variable as expected. As an experiment, I still wrote the variable to the .profile file. In addition, I added a directive in .bashrc to source the `/home/vagrant/.profile` file so I would not have to do so manually.  To prevent the box from repeatedly writing same info to .bashrc, I added a conditional based on `grep -Fxq` to peek into .bashrc and find the text string of interest. If found, don't append to the file, if not found, then append.  I will update my question to show provision block